# google maps api markers doesn't appear on the map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Making an app that uses google maps I'm making markers and initializing it as the demo on their site https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers

When I open DevTools Console in chrome I don't find any errors
[My Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVa0E.png)

Here are HTML, CSS & JS files

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Neighborhood Map</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Our Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\custom-style.css">
    <!-- Scrollbar Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css">
    <!-- -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry,drawing&key=Your_AP_KEY&v=3&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar Holder -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div id="dismiss">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></i>
            </div>

            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>Bootstrap Sidebar</h3>
            </div>

            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <p>Dummy Heading</p>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#homeSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Home</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Home 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">About</a>
                    <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Page 3</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="list-unstyled CTAs">
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/tutorial/files/sidebar.zip" class="download">Download source</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-sidebar" class="article">Back to article</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <!-- Page Navigation Bar -->
        <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left"></i>
            <span>Open Sidebar</span>
        </button>

        <!-- Page Content Holder -->
        <div id="content">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="overlay"></div>

    <!-- jQuery CDN -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Js CDN -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Custom Scroller CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
    <!-- -->
    <script src="js\lib\knockout-3.4.2.js" async></script>
    <!-- -->
    <script src="js\app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
    /*
    DEMO STYLE
*/

@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700";
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background: #fafafa;
}

p {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.7em;
    color: #999;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

.navbar {
    background: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navbar-btn {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none !important;
    border: none;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navbar-header {
    height: 30%;
}

.line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ddd;
    margin: 40px 0;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    SIDEBAR STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#sidebar {
    width: 250px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: -250px;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #7386D5;
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

#sidebar.active {
    left: 0;
}

#dismiss {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #7386D5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}

#dismiss:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 998;
    display: none;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
    padding: 20px;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul.components {
    padding: 20px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    display: block;
}

#sidebar ul li a:hover {
    color: #7386D5;
    background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a, a[aria-expanded="true"] {
    color: #fff;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapse"] {
    position: relative;
}

a[aria-expanded="false"]::before, a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e259';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 0.6em;
}

a[aria-expanded="true"]::before {
    content: '\e260';
}

ul ul a {
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    padding-left: 30px !important;
    background: #6d7fcc;
}

ul.CTAs {
    padding: 20px;
}

ul.CTAs a {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em !important;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

a.download {
    background: #fff;
    color: #7386D5;
}

a.article, a.article:hover {
    background: #6d7fcc !important;
    color: #fff !important;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------
    CONTENT STYLE
----------------------------------------------------- */

#content {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100vh;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex
}

#map {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 2;
}
```

JS

```
    // map variable holds an object from MAP class
var map;
// Markers array holds my markers
var Markers = [];
// These are the real estate listings that will be shown to the user.
var favouriteLocations = [
    { title: 'Primoz Pizza', location: { lat: 30.112503, lng: 31.348311 } },
    { title: 'El-Sadat Park', location: { lat: 30.165822, lng: 31.424106 } },
    { title: 'Chili\'s Al Merghani', location: { lat: 30.085275, lng: 31.333463 } },
    { title: 'Saudi German Hospital - Cairo', location: { lat: 30.132663, lng: 31.384305 } },
    { title: 'Post Office - El Salam City', location: { lat: 30.167742, lng: 31.413091 } },
    { title: 'Citystars Heliopolis', location: { lat: 30.072979, lng: 31.346050 } }
];
// Intiats map and adds markers
function initMap() {

    // Boundary Object to fit locations in the map
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Constructor creates a new map - only center and zoom are required.
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: 30.165822, lng: 31.424106 },
        zoom: 13
    });


    // The following group uses the favouriteLocations array to create an array of markers on initialize.
    for (let i = 0; i < favouriteLocations.length; i++) {
        // Get position & title from the locations array
        var posision = favouriteLocations[i].location;
        var title = favouriteLocations[i].title;
        debugger;
        // Create a marker per loction, and put it into Markers array.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            posision: posision,
            title:title,
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            id: i
        });
        // Push The marker to Markers Array
        Markers.push(marker);
        // Holds Boundaries of all markers
        bounds.extend(Markers[i].posision);
    }
    // Extend the boundaries of the map for each marker
    map.fitBounds(bounds);

}


// Sliders
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#sidebar").mCustomScrollbar({
        theme: "minimal"
    });

    $('#dismiss, .overlay').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').removeClass('active');
        $('.overlay').fadeOut();
    });

    $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function () {
        $('#sidebar').addClass('active');
        $('.overlay').fadeIn();
        $('.collapse.in').toggleClass('in');
        $('a[aria-expanded=true]').attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
    });
});
```

I can't figure out what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this JSBin out: http://jsbin.com/bacoyor/4/edit?js,output

I changed 'posision' to 'position' in the following code:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
 -> position: posision,
    title:title,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
    id: i
});
```

and

```
bounds.extend(Markers[i].position);
```

I also moved the script that loads the Google Maps JavaScript API to the end of the body tag.

```
<body>
    [...]
    <script src="js\app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places,geometry,drawing&key=YOUR_API_KEY&v=3&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
</body>
```

Comment: No problem @IbrahimHasan! Glad to help.